# Virtual MIDI ports not listed in Apple's MIDI Studio

Tags: coremidi

Virtual MIDI ports created by Apple's Core MIDI framework are not listed in MIDI Studio of Apple's Audio MIDI Setup, unlike the ports of hardware and Bluetooth MIDI devices.

Our Connect software (https://icubex.com/connect) creates virtual MIDI ports, using Core MIDI calls, that are accessible by many audio/MIDI software programs including Garageband, but these virtual MIDI ports do not appear in or cannot be added to Apple's MIDI Studio of Apple's Audio MIDI Setup.

Some software programs can communicate with the MIDI ports provided by MIDI Studio yet don't recognize the virtual MIDI ports created by our Connect software, so they cannot communicate directly with our software. It's then necessary to use a program like MIDI Pipe (http://www.subtlesoft.square7.net/MidiPipe.html) to forward data from the virtual MIDI port to/from the IAC driver.

How can we bypass the MIDI Pipe solution and get the virtual MIDI ports recognized and listed by MIDI Studio like other hardware and Bluetooth MIDI devices ?